# Create highchart application with extjs mvc pattern

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, highcharts, extjs4

I am new to Extjs, i wanted to create a simple highchart using Extjs MVC or MVVM pattern. Please provide me any sample application or guide me on how to do that.

My main doubt on this is how to bind the Ext.data.store data to Highchart series and categories

I had seen some examples using Sencha highchart plugin "Chart.ux.Highcharts". I dont want to use this one.

Thanks in advance for your kind help

Comment: What do u have so far? nothing? --> question is to be colsed

Comment: Simple demo in ExtJS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26875490/highchart-extjs-chart-updates